# In Emacs-lisp, what is the correct way to use call-process on an ls command?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I want to execute the following shell command in emacs-lisp:

```
ls -t ~/org *.txt | head -5
```

My attempt at the following:

```
(call-process "ls" nil t nil "-t" "~/org" "*.txt" "| head -5")
```

results in

```
ls: ~/org: No such file or directory
ls: *.txt: No such file or directory
ls: |head -5: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that tokens like `~`, `*`, and `|` aren't processed/expanded by the `ls` program. Since the tokens aren't processed, `ls` is look for a file or directory literally called `~/org`, a file or directory literally called `*.txt`, and a file or directory literally called `| head -5`. Thus the error message you received about `No such file or directory".

Those tokens are processed/expanded by the shell (like Bourne shell /bin/sh or Bash /bin/bash). Technically, interpretation of the tokens can be shell-specific, but most shell interpret at least some of the same standard tokens the same way, e.g. `|` means connecting programs together end-to-end to almost all shells. As a counterexample, Bourne shell (/bin/sh) does not do `~` tilde/home-directory expansion.

If you want to get the expansions, you have to get your calling program to do the expansion itself like a shell would (hard work) or run your `ls` command in a shell (much easier):

```
/bin/bash -c "ls -t ~/org *.txt | head -5"
```

so

```
(call-process "/bin/bash" nil t nil "-c" "ls -t ~/org *.txt | head -5")
```

*Edit:* Clarified some issues, like mentioning that `/bin/sh` doesn't do `~` expansion.

Comment: @eatload - gald to be able to help - the `shell-command` by R. P. Dillon seems like a good alternative too.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on your use case, if you find yourself wanting to execute shell commands and have the output made available in a new buffer frequently, you can also make use of the `shell-command` feature.  In your example, it would look something like this:

```
(shell-command "ls -t ~/org *.txt | head -5")
```

To have this inserted into the current buffer, however, would require that you set `current-prefix-arg` manually using something like `(universal-argument)`, which is a bit of a hack.  On the other hand, if you just want the output someplace you can get it and process it, `shell-command` will work as well as anything else.

Comment: I don't think you need to set `current-prefix-arg` manually. `shell-command` takes two optional parameters `output-buffer` and `error-buffer`.

Comment: I saw that, but noticed that if you specify `output-buffer` to be the current buffer, it says it erases the buffer first and then pushes in the result of the command, which would often be undesirable, I think.  I haven't tried it though, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: If you want output into the current buffer, you can use an argument that's neither a buffer nor nil for `output-buffer`. Then the output will inserted instead of replacing the current content. E.g. `(shell-command "ls" t)`

Comment: For the record, there's also `(insert (shell-command-to-string "echo 'shell command yay'"))`, which is sometimes a better way of doing it.